# Angular Project - handling large amounts of data by Restful API

Tags: angular, laravel, api

I have written my own Restful API in Laravel project and am wondering about the best way to deal with large amounts of records returned from the API to show them in Angular front-end project.

For example, if I use GET method to get all products data, it take 1000's. This makes using the API very sluggish., I can't use cache policies because data changes very fast, changes happen in stock and price also using local storage of browser failed due to large data size

Can anyone suggest the best way of dealing with this?

Comment: i would implement some kind of paginate logic in the backend to reduce the amount of response data. here is an example (see https://medium.com/@sgandhi132/how-to-make-a-custom-pagination-from-an-array-in-laravel-c4f4409cce70)

Comment: The best way is to use laravel pagination Or background job for large amount of data.

Comment: Pagination at REST API will be my choice of solution for this problem.

Comment: @JubishKammily , I must get all data because , I don't know what's the sold product and what's the page contain this sold product, so I get all product so it's huge data

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned I would recommend to use Pagination to reduce the large amount of data. Please look at https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/pagination

Comment: I must get all data because , I don't know what's the sold product and what's the page contain this sold product, so I get all product so it's huge data

Comment: @Hosasm i don't know exactly what you want to do, but paginate contains additional meta information such as total, current_page, last_page, etc.

Comment: I have 2 get methods , one to get sells and other to get product and at angular I print the profit of this sell by getting the sold product from the sell api and cost price from product api so I don't know which page of product api contain this sold product so I get all products